# How to set up a default value of an input generating a slider?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this following code that shows a slider where user can chose between 3 options: Pale, Medium or deep

```
 <input id="concentration" type="text"
                            data-provide="slider"
                            data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
                            data-slider-ticks-labels='["pale", "medium", "deep"]'
                            data-slider-min="1"
                            data-slider-max="3"
                            data-slider-step="1"
                            data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

How can I set up a default value if the slider is not touched ? At the moment, if the slider is not touched, the value it will get with javascript will be 3 which is the maximum value. I would like to set it to 1 per default instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `data-slider-val` or `data-slider-value` attribute.

It would look like this in your case:

```
<input id="concentration" type="text"
                            data-provide="slider"
                            data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
                            data-slider-ticks-labels='["pale", "medium", "deep"]'
                            data-slider-min="1"
                            data-slider-max="3"
                            data-slider-step="1"
                            data-slider-tooltip="hide"
                            data-slider-value="1"
 />
```

---

If I'm not mistaken you are using `Slider for Bootstrap`.

If I'm right you can visit [this](http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/f/52201/demo.html) demo page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-slider-value=""` and inside that whatever value you want as default and then it will have that value when loaded. example:

```
data-slider-value="1"
```